# Webmin MySql error message

Tags: webmin

Has anybody else had a error message like this in webmin?

```
Failed to save MySQL server options : Missing or invalid IP address to listen on
```

Comment: I understand that but its kind of rude that you just jump on peoples post and start making changes without giving them the reason first :/

Comment: But I added the text as well. Im not looking to argue but it would be nice to be told why the change has been made the first time, instead of just making the change and not explaining why.

Comment: I didnt disagree I just said it was rude that I was told, I actually was thinking I was doing something wrong but had no idea what.

Comment: Please read this: https://askubuntu.com/help/editing.  And take it up on https://meta.askubuntu.com/ if you disagree with how this site works. Again: no. Comments are also NOT for discussions.

Comment: You're quite right that edits with  no explanation are confusing. Sorry about that! In this case, the edit is done to conform with site policy as explained [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). We prefer text over screenshots since i) it is searchable; ii) it can be copied; iii) it takes less time to load and iv) it can be read by screen readers and so be accessible to blind users.

Comment: Thank you for being more understanding Terdon :) il keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file to configure the basic settings such as TCP/IP port, IP address binding, and other options. In Ubuntu 16.10, which you are using (see [Problems with the modification of Apache2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906935/problems-with-the-modification-of-apache2)), the MySQL database server configuration file is located at `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`. To edit it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

The instructions for using nano editor are always found at the bottom of every page. The only two nano keyboard shortcuts that you need to know are for WriteOut and Exit. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Then restart the MySQL server:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql.service
```